# starter icon doesnt appear with other apps -android studio

Tags: android, icons

after install my app on my device, she runs without problems, but when i want to access the app from the home menu apps, the icon doesnt appear, i look into aplication manager and the app is installed, I read others responses about that but cant figure it out, heres my manifies file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="majad.sunshine.app"><application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <data android:scheme="geo"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".DetailActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_detail"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="majad.sunshine.app.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="majad.sunshine.app.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /></manifest>
```

Ill appreciate your help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you missed an intent filter tag

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <data android:scheme="geo"/>
</intent-filter>
```

This will solve the problem.You are giving two actions in the same intent filter which was causing the problem.